# How do I search for a tuple of values in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to write a function to swap a dictionary of targets with results in a pandas dataframe. I'd like to match a tuple of values and swap out new values. I tried building it as follows, but the the row select isn't working. I feel like I'm missing some critical function here.

```
import pandas
testData=pandas.DataFrame([["Cats","Parrots","Sandstone"],["Dogs","Cockatiels","Marble"]],columns=["Mammals","Birds","Rocks"])
target=("Mammals","Birds")
swapVals={("Cats","Parrots"):("Rats","Canaries")}
for x in swapVals:
    #Attempt 1:
    #testData.loc[x,target]=swapVals[x]
    #Attempt 2:
    testData[testData.loc[:,target]==x,target]=swapVals[x]
```

Comment: please provide a required data sample, you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was written in Python 2, but the basic idea should work for you.  It uses the apply function:

```
import pandas
testData=pandas.DataFrame([["Cats","Parrots","Sandstone"],["Dogs","Cockatiels","Marble"]],columns=["Mammals","Birds","Rocks"])
swapVals={("Cats","Parrots"):("Rats","Canaries")}
target=["Mammals","Birds"]

def swapper(in_row):
    temp =tuple(in_row.values)
    if temp in swapVals:
        return list(swapVals[temp])
    else:
        return in_row

testData[target] = testData[target].apply(swapper, axis=1)

testData
```

Note that if you loaded the other keys into the dict, you could do the apply without the swapper function:

```
import pandas
testData=pandas.DataFrame([["Cats","Parrots","Sandstone"],["Dogs","Cockatiels","Marble"]],columns=["Mammals","Birds","Rocks"])
swapVals={("Cats","Parrots"):("Rats","Canaries"), ("Dogs","Cockatiels"):("Dogs","Cockatiels")}
target=["Mammals","Birds"]

testData[target] = testData[target].apply(lambda x: list(swapVals[tuple(x.values)]), axis=1)

testData
```